# How are logistics and preparations for international equestrian events dealt with?

Tags: trivia

In light of the Tokyo Olympics and how equestrian events at high level deal not only with sportsmen who need to be at their best, but *also* their rides, needing to be in absolute peak condition in order to enable a good performance on the field, I'm curious as to how much preparation goes into ensuring the horses are fit to compete.

Here are a few questions I came up with in order to better understand how complex equestrian logistics actually are:

- What is the main mode of transportation used to move the horses to their destination?

  - Are there any special processes to be undertaken **before** transportation, in order to minimise stress on the horses?
  - What special measures are taken **during** transportation, given that competing horses are not "common" livestock?
- How much in advance to the competition do the horses usually arrive on their destination?
- What measures are taken at the destination so the horses adequate to the climate of the region and recover from the trip?